# Cppdepend handling from command line

Tags: c++

I´ve downloaded the CppDepend static code analyzator, to analyze my .cpp programs. It seems to have a nice visual APK to manage my files, however, I´m more looking for something that can be controlled from the command line, so that I can create another program which runs that and does the appropriate stuff.

Visual application seems to have a quite rich Doc here: https://www.cppdepend.com/Doc/Getting-Started-with-CppDepend.pdf

but so far I have not found anything about it´s command version.

Does anyone have any experience with this or anything helpful to share?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can execute CppDepend from the terminal or any script using [CppDepend.Console.exe](https://www.cppdepend.com/CppDependConsole)